# Hacer toggle() sidenav desde el componente

Tags: angular

Se que se puede hacer el toggle() del sidenav desde el código HTML de la siguiente manera

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [opened]="true">
      <md-nav-list>
      </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Close</button>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Cómo podría hacer `sidenav.toggle()` del sidenav desde el código del componente en vez de usando el evento click?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar lo siguiente en el componente:

```
@ViewChild('sidenav',{static: true}) referencia : any;
```

Y luego llamar al método `toggle()`:

```
llamarToggle(){
   this.referencia.toggle();
}
```

Y agrega el import del `ViewChild` si no está importado:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```